# PhpStorm with PHPUnit in PHP docker container on vagrant

Tags: docker, phpunit, vagrant, phpstorm

I have the Vagrant box with several containers and one container is for PHP engine.

Usually, I run my tests inside Vagrant box like:

```
docker run <my_specific_parameteres> remote.docker.container.php7.2 bin/phpunit --coverage-clover -c phpunit.xml.dist
```

But, I want to run this with PhpStorm. It is possible? If yes, any help, because I do not know how to properly configure my PhpStorm to run PHPUnit as I want.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit complicated because there is one extra virtualization layer (host => Vagrant VM => Docker), but it's possible.

Let's agree on these:

- `/home/PhpstormProjects/theProject` is the path of your sources on the host.
- `/var/www/html/theProject` is the Vagrant VM path your sources are mapped into.
- `/opt/theProject` is the container path the Vagrant path is bound to with volume mappings.

First, you need to configure your Docker daemon to listen on TCP port:
https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-enable-the-remote-api-for-dockerd

Then, you need to add these Docker server at PhpStorm `Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Docker`.

After that, add a Docker remote interpreter using the desired image at PhpStorm `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP`.

You need to set the following mappings later:

- Docker container | Volume bindings:

  - Container path: `/opt/theProject`
  - Host path: `/var/www/html/theProject`
- Path mappings: Add a new mapping (as the default one is incorrect):

  - Local path: `/home/PhpstormProjects/theProject`
  - Remote path: `/opt/theProject`

After that, configure PHPUnit for this Docker interpreter at `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Test Frameworks`, it should be able to parse paths OK.

That's basically it, you should be good to go. Unfortunately, there's no option to pass custom arguments to Docker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181088

If there are any issues, please submit a support request: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us